# jQuery multiple input types in one form

Tags: jquery, file, input

I got multiple input types in my form based on positions.

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" data-positionid="<?php echo $positionId; ?>" class="inputfile" />
```

Now i want on change the correct data-positionid to show.
If i got multiple positions the jQuery i got responds only to the first every time.

```
        $('input[type=file]').change(function () {

        var positionId = $(this).data('productid');
        alert(positionId);
    });
```

So i think that $(this) is not realy getting the changed input type.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code:

```
$('input[type=file]').eq(0).change(function () {

        var positionId = $(this).data('productid');
        alert(positionId);
    });
```

The above code will trigger element at the 0th index that is the first element.

Comment: Hi, this will get the first input type only. What i want is if i got multiple positions, so code example 1 is there multiple times, get for example input type positionId of the third input type.

Comment: Are you saying that the event is getting applied multiple times to the same element ?

Comment: Yes it is. I want for every position an image upload field. And based on the position id i know where to upload the image.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" data-positionid="<?php echo $positionId; ?>" class="inputfile" onchange="getProductId(<?php echo $positionId; ?>)"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getProductId(positionId) {
        alert("Value is " + positionId);
}
 </script>
```